# Sharepoint Blog Deployment

Tags: blog, deployment, feature

I modified the aspx files with Sharepoint Designer of the default sharepoint blog to change its layout. Now, I'd like to know if there is a way to package that in a feature or something like that to put it in QA and production. (I've tried sharepoint solution generator but it doesn't support blogs)

I'm using Sharepoint 2007 (MOSS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using SharePoint 2010 you can save your Blog site to a Template (as a WSP file) which can then be exported and distributed, and even opened and modified further in Visual Studio.

SharePoint 2007 lets you do the same but saves .STP files, however you cannot open these in Visual Studio.

you can do either via Site Actions -> Site Settings -> Save as Site Template

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I saved my blog as a template and then followed the procedure there (from #5) :
http://rehmangul.wordpress.com/2007/02/02/uploading-a-site-template-in-moss-2007/